# Start processes to run in parallel

Tags: bash, process

I am trying to start 16 python scripts in parallel.

I tried to do

```
for i in {0..15}
    do
    python my_script.py "$i"
    done
```

But checking my `htop` this only runs on one processor. I am guessing that the process are being executed in sequence.

I can of course open a new tab and run a process in each tab, but that seems to be redundant. What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for `&` which will run jobs in the background:

```
for i in {0..15}
do
    python my_script.py "$i" &
done
```

That will launch all 15 simultaneously. Alternatively, for more fine grained control, you might want to check out [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

For more information on the various shell control operators, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/22222).